# OpenCV Android remove light intensity from captured frame

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to make an AR app using opencv that detects certain objects emitting colored light. The thought process for accomplishing this is as follows:

Get incoming frame in rgb matrix -> copy frame to another matrix -> do image processing on the copy -> detect objects based on color of light emitted -> overlay graphics on original matrix and return it

My problem is that the camera's exposure compensation on my android phone, combined with background light from the room and light intensity from the objects themselves, is over-saturating the frame and drowning out the color from the objects.

The camera functions lockAutoExposure() and getMinExposureCompensation() do a nice job of preserving the color of light the objects emit, but they affect the original frame since this code affects the camera itself, before I can copy the frame into another placeholder matrix. I was wondering if there are opencv functions that accomplish the same effect at the image processing step of the pipeline, rather than changing how the camera captures each frame.

Thanks!

Comment: why do you need a darkened min exposure frame for processing? and what do you mean with that? I don't understand your problem. and what is a "normal" frame?

Comment: I have edited my question based on your response. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: it still doesn't make any sense to me. if you want to display another image than you want to process you have to capture two different images. but why do you want to process a dark image in the first place? btw those auto exposure functions influence the exposure time the camera uses to capture images. they do not process the images! that's something totally different...

Comment: Edited once more. See if it makes more sense now